# Adorning screenshots with NSStrings inside an NSImage

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsimage

I'm trying to grab a screenshot from a NSView, draw a string on top of the screenshot using the NSImage buffer then saving everything. The view grabbed from is a plain NSPanel contentview that hosts a single NSImageView.

Unfortunately the output file is my string on an all black background with no sign of the screenshot.

This is the code:

```
NSImage *screenshot = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:[mView dataWithPDFInsideRect:[mView bounds]]];

NSString *frameCounterString = @"123";
[screenshot lockFocus];
[frameCounterString drawAtPoint:NSMakePoint(10, 10) withAttributes:nil];
[screenshot unlockFocus];
```

Any ideas what's going on?

Writing the image directly, i.e. no string drawing yields the expected result (= screenshot in file).

As soon as the lockFocus/unlockFocus calls are added in the result goes black..

Using the NSBitmapImageRep:initWithFocusedViewRect: technique for capturing doesn't work either in this case, i.e.:

```
  screenshot = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:[mView bounds].size];
  [mView lockFocus];
  NSBitmapImageRep *bits = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithFocusedViewRect:[mView bounds]];
  [mView unlockFocus];
  [screenshot addRepresentation:bits];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right - now compositing several NSImages as suggested by the Apple docs.
One for the screenshot, than drawing that plus the string into a new empty NSImage.

Still black.

The view to be captured contains a NSImageView and it must be something about its internal image representations: setting the NSImageView border to none doesn't yield any screenshot, ever. Setting the border to 'Photo' allows it to be captured using the dataWithPDFInsideRect method.

Need to find a more generic way to capture it no matter what the display mode is..

Comment: Is it only an image view, or are there other views in the view to be captured?

Comment: It's just a single image view: `Window -> Content View -> NSImageView`. Capturing the content or image view doesn't really make a difference in terms of the result (both black)

Comment: If it's just an image view and all you want is the image, then you can ask the image view for its image, make a copy, and draw the string into that (if you're not trying to make something able to handle any view).

Comment: Well, yes - I was hoping for a **generic** way to capture any view.. that bit of code is actually part of a view recorder class that was supposed to be usable with anywhere. After two days of frustration I'd be happy to capture any view in any window just in my app with it, though.

Comment: **D'oh!!** Adding two lines to the composited NSImage fixes this: `[[NSColor whiteColor] setFill]; NSRectFill([mView bounds]);` ... I was drawing black graphics with transparent stuff on top of a black background.......

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why that wouldn't work (you may want to [file a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com/)), but what I'd suggest doing instead is this:

1. Create a new NSImage of the desired size.
2. Lock focus on it.
3. Tell the view to `display`.
4. Draw the string.
5. Unlock focus.